# AngularJS: Form validation whereas html is not displayed

Tags: angularjs, forms, routes

I'm developing an application containing several forms, each included in a specific route.
I need to validate all those forms on a global button click. But one form is displayed only, the others don't exist.
How can I process this validation whereas the HTML containing the validation rules (ng-required, ...) is not instantiated?
Thanks.

Vincent.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, at least not easily. Why not validate a form at a time?

Comment: Why do you have multiple forms and one button? why don't you wrap all the forms in one so you have one big form instead of x forms?

Comment: You might need to persist the form data to a service and then on submit, validate those values.  But I agree that with the other comments that it doesn't seem like the greatest approach to UI.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't the final say over UI issues. Thanks for the replies.